# Javascript date array sorting with minute seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, date, datetime

I have an array of a few objects:

```
var array = [
{id: 1, date: Mar 12 2012 10:00:12}, 
{id: 2, date: Mar 12 2012 08:00:43}
];
```

I am using this code:

```
array.sort ((a, b) => {
   return new Date(a.DateTime) - new Date(b.DateTime); 
});
```

How can I sort this array with date time with seconds.

I can not get sorting date with seconds. without seconds its sorting correctly.

Would I use the sort function and a custom comparator?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="sortList" style="padding:10px; border:1px solid #ff0000;">
    sorted<hr />  
  </div>
  </body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function ubsrt()
{
  myList = new Array();
  myList[0]               = {};
  myList[0]['id']      = '1';
  myList[0]['date']       = '2015-09-26'; 

  myList[1]               = {};
  myList[1]['id']      = '2';
  myList[1]['date']       = '2016-10-11';
  
myList.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
})

  $.each(myList, function(i)
  {
      $('#sortList').append('Id='+myList[i]['id']+'<span>| Date='+myList[i]['date']+'<span><br />'); 
  });

});
      
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: The above code is working without second.please check it